How to relate the two expressions of thermal spectrum?
I am reading a proof of the fact that if there exists a monochromatic plane electromagnetic wave for an observer in frame $S$, an observer in a frame $S'$, which is uniformly accelerated with respect to $S$ sees a thermal spectrum. I quote some references I have been reading at the bottom. I understand the argument, but my issue is that the thermal spectrum expression each of them derive is the following (modulo some proportionality factors):
$$\frac{1}{E}\frac{1}{e^{\beta E}-1}$$
All of them say that this is a thermal spectrum. I have grown up seeing that the thermal power spectrum is given by (again modulo proportionality factors):
$$\frac{E^3}{e^{\beta E}-1}$$
I am unable to see how to connect the two. One possibility is that perhaps the first expression is not taking into account the density of states factor. I am confused whether that should get me a multiplicative factor of $E^3$ or $E^2$. But neither of them does the job. I need a factor of $E^4$, and I have no sense of where that is coming from.
Here are the references I have been talking about:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0401170.pdf (See equation 9)
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.07683.pdf (See equation 5)
https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0311036.pdf (See equation 24)

The expression they give seems to be consistent with the detailed balance of a thermal distribution. Maybe calculating the detailed balance is what is missing for you

is the spectrum versus energy or wavelength? A $dE$, $d\nu$,  $d\lambda$.

@NíckolasAlves Could you elaborate a little more?

@JEB This is versus energy.

So comments are not because I am curious, they are hints to make the question more clear.

@Singh The detailed balance is a microscopic condition that is used to quantify equilibrium. While your two spectra are different, I believe both of them satisfy the thermal detailed balance. For more information on the detailed balance, I recommend arXiv: 1503.04342. My personal StatMech lecture notes also discuss this
